# D3 stratify: Does it have depth limits

Tags: d3.js

I've been working with D3 radial dendrograms ([link here](https://blockbuilder.org/lorenzopub/526f5145c24c0a1c9f0b237102b23cd1)). Everything works well until I try to add a node at a depth of 5. I suspect this is a constraint. I've look and cannot find any reference to this and, more importantly, whether this is a default that can be overridden. I have dendrograms need greater depth. Comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no constraint, as you can see inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/46f9e8bf1a5a55e94c40158c23025f405adf0be5/src/stratify.js#L20).

We can also easily demonstrate it. Here is an hierarchy with 10 levels:

```js
const csv = `id,parentId
level1,
level2,level1
level3,level2
level4,level3
level5,level4
level6,level5
level7,level6
level8,level7
level9,level8
level10,level9
level11,level10`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

const root = d3.stratify()(data);

console.log("This hierarchy has " + root.height + " levels")

console.log(root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. If you look at the link in my question and then the html template there, it uses the standard d3 v4 script: <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>. So I'm not sure how to use d3.stratify in that context.

Comment: @DavidAStumpf I just changed my snippet to use D3 v4, it still works.

Comment: My data is in flare format aa sample of which is here:
id,value
flare,
flare.0,
flare.0.0,
flare.0.0.4195,0
flare.0.0.4203,0
flare.0.0.6012,0
flare.0.0.4868,0
flare.0.0.4200,0
flare.0.0.4651,0
flare.0.0.6013,0
flare.0.0.7881,0
flare.0.0.5363,0
flare.0.0.7762,0
flare.0.0.6705,0
flare.1,
flare.1.1,
flare.1.1.3096,0
flare.1.3,
....

There's a lot of extra javascript in the template, but I cannot see anything that constrains the depth. But when I add a 5th level, the screen is blank

Comment: It's impossible to help you with just this information. So, please create a blockbuilder  reproducing the issue.

Comment: I started to set up a blockbuilder and saw my error. I was not adding the proper parent when trying to add a new level. Your coaching got me there & I've accepted your solution. I can add to a depth of 5+